# How can i navigate to homescreen after facebook authentication using firebase + expo

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Hello I'm new to react native and I'm trying to navigate to Home Screen with a successful authentication, but this generates an error, can someone help me? please

```
loginWithFacebook = async() => {
await Facebook.initializeAsync(
  '235487284376992',
);

const { type, token } = await Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync(
  { permissions: ['public_profile'] }
);

if (type === 'success') {

  const credential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(token);
  this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')
  firebase
  .auth().signInWithCredential(credential).catch(error => {
   console.log(error);
  });

}
```

Firebase is working, however an error is generated during navigation

[The error when try login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDhop.jpg)

this error only happens after the first authentication, then the navigation normally occurs

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `react-native-firebase`?
Which version are you using?
If you are using `react-native-firebase` v6+ , you need to install `@react-native-firebase/auth` module.
React Native Firebase version 6 has been re-created from the ground up.
And also, you must import the `firebase` from auth module on header

```
import {firebase} from "@react-native-firebase/auth";
```

This is my code.

```js
import {
  createTypes,
  createAction,
  transformNetworkError,
  socialLoginError,
} from '../../utils/actions';

import {getWithData} from '../../utils/request';
import {OneSignalUtils} from '../../utils/oneSignalUtils';
import {FirebaseUtils} from '../../utils/firebaseServices';
import { LoginManager, AccessToken } from 'react-native-fbsdk';
import { GoogleSignin } from '@react-native-community/google-signin';
import {firebase} from "@react-native-firebase/auth";

const facebookLogin = () => async dispatch => {
  const loginAction = {
    do: () => createAction(LOGIN.DO, {}),
    success: (response, authData) => createAction(LOGIN.SUCCESS, {userData: response, authData: authData}),
    failed: (error) => createAction(LOGIN.FAILED, error),
  };
  try {
    dispatch(loginAction.do());
    const result = await LoginManager.logInWithPermissions(['public_profile', 'email']);
    if (result.isCancelled) {
      dispatch(loginAction.failed(socialLoginError({status: true, message: 'Facebook login canceled.'})));
    }
    const logindata = await AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
    if (!logindata) {
      dispatch(loginAction.failed(socialLoginError({status: true, message: 'Something went wrong obtaining access token.'})));
      return null;
    } else {
      const credential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(logindata.accessToken);
      const firebaseUserCredential = await firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential);
      const data = firebaseUserCredential.user.toJSON();
      await FirebaseUtils.userRef.doc(data.uid).set(data);
      dispatch(loginAction.success());
      return data;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('facebook login error', e);
    dispatch(loginAction.failed(socialLoginError({status: true, message: 'Something went wrong.'})));
    return null;
  }
};
```

Comment: I am using v7.9.0. I installed all dependencies, 
my google authentication works normal, i'm having problems only with facebook

Comment: are you using react-native-fbsdk?
Added my code into my post.

Comment: import * as firebase from 'firebase'
import * as Facebook from 'expo-facebook';

Comment: according to the documentation [link](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/facebook/) I just need to run expo install expo-facebook on the terminal and import the API using import * as Facebook from 'expo-facebook';